# Django Rest Framework Mongoengine - PUT/PATCH vs GET for ReferenceField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, mongoengine

I have two mongoengine Document **models** as:

```
from mongoengine import *

class Doc1(Document):
  doc1_field1 = StringField(max_length=100)
  doc1_field2 = StringField(max_length=100)

class Doc2(Document):
  doc2_field1 = ReferenceField(Doc1)
  doc2_field2 = StringField(max_length=100)
```

in **serializers.py**:

```
from rest_framework_mongoengine import serializers
from .models import Doc1, Doc2

class Doc1Serializer(serializers.DocumentSerializer):

   class Meta:          
      model = Doc1
      fields = '__all__'

class Doc2Serializer(serializers.DocumentSerializer):

   doc2_field1 = Doc1Serializer()

   class Meta:
      model = Doc2
      fields = ('doc2_field1', 'doc2_field2')
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework_mongoengine import viewsets
from .models import Doc2
from .serializers import Doc2Serializer

class Doc2ViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

   lookup_field = 'pk'

   serializer_class = Doc2Serializer

   def get_queryset(self):
     return Doc2.objects.all()
```

What I'm trying to achieve is when I make a **GET** request the *`doc2_field1`*  should come dereferenced based on the *`Doc1Serializer`* and this is actually the case right now. The problem is when I try to PUT/PATCH a *`doc2_field1`* with a new ObjectID reference as defined in `models.py`. That is where I get the following:

> "non_field_errors": [
>                       "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got str."
>                   ]

So my question is if there is a way to get a field dereferenced in **`GET`** but allow for Object references in **`PUT/PATCH`**.

**EXPECTED:**

**GET:**

```
{
  "doc2_field1": {
  "doc1_field1": "Text Value 1",
  "doc1_field2": "Text Value 2"
  },
  "doc2_field2": "Text Value"
}
```

**PUT/PATCH:**

```
{
  "doc2_field1": "5ae1a104e35e8620801798f3"
  "doc2_field2": "Text Value"
}
```

Comment: Can you add examples what data do you need to PUT and what you expect from GET?

Comment: **GET**:

`{
  "doc2_field1": {
    "doc1_field1": "Text Value 1",
    "doc1_field2": "Text Value 2"
  }
  "doc2_field2": "Text Value"
}`

**PUT/PATCH**:

`{
  "doc2_field1": "5ae1a104e35e8620801798f3"
  "doc2_field2": "Text Value"
}`

PUT a ReferenceId, GET referenced object data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override Doc2Serializer's `to_representation` method to show details only for GET requests:

```
class Doc2Serializer(serializers.DocumentSerializer):

   class Meta:
      model = Doc2
      fields = ('doc2_field1', 'doc2_field2')

   def to_representation(self, instance):
      self.fields['doc2_field1'] = Doc1Serializer()
      return super(Doc2Serializer, self).to_representation(instance)
```

Comment: Simpler than I thought... Thank you very much!